# Separate taskbar shortcuts for Outlook Web Mail and Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-edge, outlook-web-access

Using Chrome or Edge you can install Outlook (from Office 365) as a PWA / taskbar icon. However, it will always default to the Mail section of the Outlook PWA. Is there a way to add a second icon to the taskbar that always opens the Calendar in a dedicated window like a PWA does?

I am okay with installing a second browser for that e.g., Edge Beta.

Reason is that I like to have Email under [START] + 1 and Calendar under [START] + 2. This was easily possible with Google Gmail and Calendar which are two seperate PWAs and can be installed as such.

A solution that doesn't work like a PWA but just opens Calendar in a dedicated non-tabbed window is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about the desktop version of Outlook,
create two shortcuts on your desktop called `Calendar` and `Inbox`,
right-click them an select "Pin to taskbar". The two will point to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select Outlook:Calendar
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select Outlook:Inbox
```

For the Web version:

- Open the webpage that you want in Chrome or Microsoft Edge
- Click on the vertical 3-dots icon menu
- Hover on "More Tools"
- Click on "Create Shortcut…"
- Customize the link title and also enable or disable the checkbox to open
  the link in a window
- Click the "Create" button
- This will create a shortcut link and place it on the desktop screen,
  that you may now pin to the taskbar.

Comment: The current version of Edge doesn't show "Create Shortcut..." is shows Save page as, Cast media to device, Pin to taskbar, Pin to Start, Launch taskbar pinning wizard, Browser task manager & Developer tools. 

And when I am on the Calendar page the Pin to taskbar, Pin to Start options are both missing, probably because I already added the Outlook shortcut to the taskbar which is on the same domain. Also uninstalled the PWA of Outlook and tried to create 2 Pin to taskbars for both, which would only allow one and not allow for the New window option.

Comment: It seems like for Microsoft Edge this is done via *Apps > Install this site as an app*, then *Apps > Manage apps*, right-click on the created application and "Create Shortcut…".

Comment: But that will still go to the inbox instead of the calendar

Comment: Doesn't that depend on which page you make into an app?

Comment: No it does not, I've tried all sorts of ways